# Calling a SAP ME web Service in wcf web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I have a soap web service (sap me web service), I generated the wcf proxy. no problem,  I developed a WinForms application no problem
Now i try to use it in my wcf service (webHttpBinding binding in domain network) but i have an authentication error:
WCF - The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="mySoapServiceName"
It is IIS User problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SAP is using basic auth. You need to specify the username and password after you have created the proxy, for example:

```
proxy.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "joe";
proxy.Credentials.UserName.Password = "doe";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("url de mon web service soap");

SfcServices.SFCProcessingInClient myClient = new SfcServices.SFCProcessingInClient(myBinding, ea);

myClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _MESwsLogin;
myClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _MESwsPassword;

SfcServices.SFCStateRequestMessage_sync srm = new SfcServices.SFCStateRequestMessage_sync();
SfcServices.SFCStateRequest sr = new SfcServices.SFCStateRequest();
srm.SfcStateRequest = sr;
sr.SiteRef = new SfcServices.SiteRef();
sr.SiteRef.Site = _MESsite;
sr.SfcRef = new SfcServices.SFCRef();
sr.SfcRef.Sfc = "12345678903";

sr.includeSFCStepList = true;

SfcServices.SFCStateConfirmationMessage_sync response = myClient.FindStateByBasicData(srm);
strOrdreFab = response.SfcStateResponse.SFCStatus.Sfc.ShopOrderRef.ShopOrder;
strCodeProduit = response.SfcStateResponse.SFCStatus.Sfc.ItemRef.Item;
strIndice = response.SfcStateResponse.SFCStatus.Sfc.ItemRef.Revision;
```